# Trying to make A dagger in minecraft (with eclipse) that makes you teleport when right clicking

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I've been making a mod for Minecraft 1.12.2 through eclipse. I added a dagger that when right clicked should teleport you five blocks further. The only way I could think of to do this was in the item class with the onItemRightClick method, and tried using playerIn.moveForward but I don't know how to use it, and tried using moveRelative, but I don't know how to use it either. this is the current code:

```
 `public ActionResult<ItemStack> onItemRightClick(World worldIn, EntityLivingBase playerIn, EnumHand 
 handIn)
 {
    Vec3d forward = playerIn.getForward();
    Object move = playerIn.moveRelative(0.0F, 0.0F, 3.0F, 0.0F);
    return //I don't know what to add here yet
 }`
```

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I know nothing about this code, but if you are extending a base class then you should just be able to defer to the superclass, right? `return super.onItemRightClick(worldIn, playerIn, handIn);`

Comment: I don't think the "Vec3d" part is needed, but I don't see how I could use the superclass

Comment: I just looked back at this and realized I wrote it kinda wierd. I was trying to say that my problem isn't the method but the content in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer by looking up different components of my script online, this is what I ended up with:

```
@Override
    public ActionResult<ItemStack> onItemRightClick(World worldIn, EntityPlayer player, EnumHand handIn) 
    {
        player.getCooldownTracker().setCooldown(this, 20); //Sets a cooldown of one second
        {
            Vec3d look = player.getLookVec(); //Lets you check the coordinates the player is facing
            player.setVelocity(look.x, look.y, look.z); //setting the player's velocity towards the direction they are looking at
            return super.onItemRightClick(worldIn, player, handIn); //A return method, since this method isn't a void
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if you still need it, but here is how I did it.

```
if (worldIn.getBlockState(pos).allowsMovement(worldIn, pos, PathType.LAND)) {
                
                playerIn.getCooldownTracker().setCooldown(stack.getItem(), 30);
                playerIn.setPosition(playerIn.getPosX() + x * dist, playerIn.getPosY() + y * dist + 1, playerIn.getPosZ() + z * dist);
}
```

Kind of does the same thing as you want it! I teleports you in the direction you are looking. You might want to set a max range for your item!

Comment: I don't, actually. I was originally trying to make the item teleport me a few blocks forward and turn me around (180 degrees). I ended up figuring it out by myself, but felt that my original temporary solution, having the dagger launch you in a direction, was more fun and useful, so I stuck with that. Thanks anyway, and sorry for the late reply.